# Correct way of writing recursive functions in CLP(R) with Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, clp, clpr

I am very confused in how CLP works in Prolog. Not only do I find it hard to see the benefits (I do see it in specific cases but find it hard to generalise those) but more importantly, I can hardly make up how to correctly write a recursive predicate. Which of the following would be the correct form in a CLP(R) way?

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, F):- {
  N > 0,
  PrevN = N - 1,
  factorial(PrevN, NewF),
  F = N * NewF}.
```

or

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, F):- {
  N > 0,
  PrevN = N - 1,
  F = N * NewF},
  factorial(PrevN, NewF).
```

In other words, I am not sure when I should write code outside the constraints. To me, the first case would seem more logical, because `PrevN` and `NewF` belong to the constraints. But if that's true, I am curious to see in which cases it is useful to use predicates outside the constraints *in a recursive function*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several overlapping questions and issues in your post, probably too many to coherently address to your complete satisfaction in a single post.

Therefore, I would like to state a few general principles first, and then—based on that—make a few specific comments about the code you posted.

First, I would like to address what I think is most important in your case:

## LP ⊆ CLP

This means simply that CLP can be regarded as a **superset** of logic programming (LP). Whether it is to be considered a **proper** superset or if, in fact, it makes even more sense to regard them as denoting the same concept is somewhat debatable. In my personal view, logic programming *without* constraints is much harder to understand and much less usable than *with* constraints. Given that also even the very first Prolog systems had a constraint like `dif/2` and also that essential built-in predicates like `(=)/2` perfectly fit the notion of "constraint", the boundaries, if they exist at all, seem at least somewhat artificial to me, suggesting that:

## LP ≈ CLP

Be that as it may, the key concept when working with CLP (of any kind) is that the **constraints** are available as **predicates**, and used in Prolog programs like all other predicates.

Therefore, whether you have the goal `factorial(N, F)` or `{ N > 0 }` is, at least *in principle*, the same concept: *Both* mean that something *holds*.

Note the **syntax**: The CLP(ℛ) constraints have the form `{ C }`, which is `{}(C)` in prefix notation.

Note that the goal `factorial(N, F)` is **not** a CLP(ℛ) constraint! Neither is the following:

```
?- { factorial(N, F) }.
ERROR: Unhandled exception: type_error({factorial(_3958,_3960)},...)
```

Thus, `{ factorial(N, F) }` is **not** a CLP(ℛ) constraint either!

Your first example therefore cannot work *for this reason alone already*. (In addition, you have a syntax error in the clause head: `factorial (`, so it also does not compile at all.)

When you learn working with a constraint solver, check out the **predicates** it provides. For example, CLP(ℛ) provides `{}/1` and a few other predicates, and has a dedicated **syntax** for stating relations that hold about *floating point numbers* (in this case).

Other constraint solver provide their *own* predicates for describing the entities of their *respective* domains. For example, CLP(FD) provides `(#=)/2` and a few other predicates to reason about **integers**. `dif/2` lets you reason about *any* Prolog term. And so on.

From the programmer's perspective, this is exactly *the same* as using *any other predicate* of your Prolog system, whether it is built-in or stems from a library. In principle, it's all the same:

A goal like `list_length(Ls, L)` can be read as: "The length of the list `Ls` is `L`."

A goal like `{ X = A + B }` can be read as: The number `X` is equal to the *sum* of `A` and `B`. For example, if you are using CLP(Q), it is clear that we are talking about **rational** numbers in this case.

In your second example, the **body** of the clause is a **conjunction** of the form `(A, B)`, where `A` is a CLP(ℛ) constraint, and `B` is a goal of the form `factorial(PrevN, NewF)`.

The point is: The CLP(ℛ) constraint is **also** a goal! Check it out:

```
?- write_canonical({a,b,c}).
{','(a,','(b,c))}
true.
```

So, you are simply using `{}/1` from `library(clpr)`, which is one of the predicates it exports.

You are right that `PrevN` and `NewF` *belong to the constraints*. However, `factorial(PrevN, NewF)` is not part of the *mini-language* that CLP(ℛ) implements for reasoning over floating point numbers. Therefore, you *cannot* pull this goal into the CLP(ℛ)-specific part.

From a programmer's perspective, a major attraction of CLP is that it *blends in* completely seamlessly into "normal" logic programming, to the point that it can in fact hardly be distinguished at all from it: The constraints are simply predicates, and written down like all other goals.

Whether you label a library predicate a "constraint" or not hardly makes any difference: *All* predicates can be regarded as constraints, since they can only *constrain* answers, never *relax* them.

Note that *both* examples you post *are recursive*! That's perfectly OK. In fact, recursive predicates will likely be the *majority* of situations in which you use constraints in the future.

However, for the concrete case of *factorial*, your Prolog system's **CLP(FD)** constraints are likely a better fit, since they are completely dedicated to reasoning about *integers*.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I guess the part that I find hard to get around is how the constraint solver works *inside* Prolog. For instance, considering the second code example I gave is correct, my initial idea about constraints was wrong. I thought that a constraint block was *first* solved (as the first goal in a goal list), but that it couldn't contain any unsolved variables. In other words, I didn't see how the recursive call could be outside/after the curly brackets if the constraint block needed the values it produced.

Comment: A major attraction of logic programming in general is that it *frees* you to a large extent from such procedural considerations. Especially if you are only beginning to learn Prolog and constraints, focus an a clear *declarative* description, *independent* of how the goals are ordered. As long as you stick to the pure and monotonic subset of Prolog (to which all constraints also belong), you can freely reorder all your goals, and learn about procedural aspects at any stage, also later. How it works inside Prolog is much harder to understand. For example, how does `(=)/2` work inside Prolog?

Comment: For example, a good way to read the second example is to say: "**If** it is the case that `N > 0`, **and** it is the case that ... etc., **then** it is the case that `factorial(N, F)` holds". How you order the constraints may have a procedural effect, but do not let that distract you from the meaning of the clause, and from the fact that you can freely reorder the goals without affecting the declarative meaning.